# AudioKit AKFader automation

Tags: audiokit

I can't find any specific info/help on creating AKFader automations. I just want to automate a fade-out and a fade-in of my main output/mixer. I see AKAutomatable, but there's no useful info on that, and AKParameterAutomation isn't in the docs at all. Any tips?

Comment: Automation is being worked on mostly for AudioKit 5, so that accounts for the lack of documentation, somewhat. There are a few people doing automation in AudioKit, and can discuss it on the AudioKit Slack channel, maybe you can request to get on that.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, Aure. I'll try joining the Slack group.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka, I poked a couple of members about getting on the Slack group but haven't heard anything, so I'm wondering if you could reach out to the folks working on automation and forward them this question? Obviously I can try something outside AK, but would rather use an AK-based solution, if possible.

Comment: Email me to get on the slack group, any of my email addresses should work.